# can someone please help to understand the following equation?

Tags: combinatorics

I would like to understand how the equation of coverage of two sets work, the equation is as the following:

$$\mathscr{C}(A,B)=\frac{|\{b\in B\mid \exists a\in A:a\succeq b\}|}{|B|}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say that $b\in B$ is *covered by $A$* if there is some $a\in A$ such that $a\succeq b$. Then

$$\{b\in B\mid\exists a\in A:a\succeq b\}$$

is simply the set of elements of $B$ that are covered by $A$, so

$$|\{b\in B\mid\exists a\in A:a\succeq b\}|$$

is the number of elements of $B$ that are covered by $A$, and

$$\mathscr{C}(A,B)=\frac{|\{b\in B\mid\exists a\in A:a\succeq b\}|}{|B|}$$

is therefore the fraction of $B$’s elements that are covered by $A$. If $\mathscr{C}(A,B)=\frac14$, a quarter of $B$’s elements are covered by $A$; if $\mathscr{C}(A,B)=1$, **every** $b\in B$ is covered by $A$.

For example, suppose that

$$X=\{000,001,010,011,100,101,110,111\}\,,$$

and say that $x_1x_2x_3\succeq y_1y_2y_3$ if $x_1\ge y_1,x_2\ge y_2$, and $x_3\ge y_3$. Let

$$A=\{000,011,100\}$$

and

$$B=\{000,010,101\}\,.$$

Then $000$ is weakly dominated by every member of $A$, $010$ is weakly dominated by $011\in A$, and $101$ is not weakly dominated by any element of $A$, so

$$\{b\in B:\exists a\in A\,(a\succeq b)\}=\{000,010\}\,,$$

and

$$\mathscr{C}(A,B)=\frac23\,.$$

Comment: Could you please add an example?

Comment: What is the absolute "| |"mean?

Comment: @AymanKhallel: If $X$ is a finite set, $|X|$ is the number of elements in $X$. Before I give an example, let me make sure that it fits this setting: is $\succeq$ a partial order?

Comment: As I know the symbol { | or : } is to define Set but why we have | and :  symbols ?

Comment: a ⪰ b means that a dominate b.

Comment: @AymanKhallel: Would it be clearer if I wrote $$\mathscr{C}(A,B)=\frac{|\{b\in B:\exists a\in A\,(a\succeq b)\}|}{|B|}\,?$$ It doesn’t help to say that it means that $a$ dominates $b$, since I don’t know what kind of relation domination is. Is it a partial order (reflexive, antisymmetric, and transitive)? A preorder (reflexive and transitive, but not necessarily antisymmetric)?

Comment: I am not sure, but I found someone write it 
C(A, B) = |{b ∈ B, there exists a ∈ A such that a ⪰ b}/|B|

Comment: @AymanKhallel: Yes, that’s the same as the expression in the question and also the one in my last comment: they all mean the same thing. In other words, $\mathscr{C}(A,B)$ is the fraction of $B$’s elements that are dominated by at least one element of $A$.

Comment: I got the equation from http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.433.2828&rep=rep1&type=pdf
equation number (3.1)

Comment: @AymanKhallel: Okay; $\succeq$ is a [preorder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preorder).

Comment: Please give me like to my question

Comment: @AymanKhallel: I’ve added a very simple example.